# Qt transfer Packet to application -- from receive thread

Tags: qt

I am working on GUI application that receives data from USB to CAN interface. Now I want this data to be shown in the Qt GUI.

I am a wx-widget user and there i uses an event handler from receive thread to send data to the GUI application

event handler in wx-widget :---

```
wxCommandEvent eventReceive( wxVSCP_IN_EVENT, test::ID_TEST_1 );
```

Set data for event handler and trigger the event in wx-widget :--

```
eventReceive.SetClientData( msg_5 );
wxPostEvent( m_pMainThreadObj->m_pCtrlObject->m_pVSCPSessionWnd, eventReceive );
```

Is there a way i can send data to my GUI from Qt lower layer ?

Brief :---
I need to pass data packet received in the receive thread.. to the GUI application. Gui is an Tabview with textview inside one tab.

[image]

Comment: Could you rewrite your question to make it clear? First - write what you are doing (with code samples), second - describe what you are expecting to see. We don't know how "my GUI" looks like and how it works. We don't know that you mean by "Qt lower layer"

Comment: I have edited my post above. Please suggest.

Comment: Use signals and slots. It's Qt basics - http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/signalsandslots.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Qt, each thread that has an event loop running in it will also have an event queue. So in your receive thread all you need to do is to post an event to some object in the GUI thread. Do note that `qApp->postEvent(...)` is thread safe and can be called from any thread.

If your CAN-to-USB dongle is exposed on the Windows side as a serial port, you can use the QtSerialPort. In that case you don't even need a separate thread.

Comment: means its just like emitting a signal which calls respective slot ?

Comment: Events and signal-slot connections are two separate mechanisms. An event is simply an object that you insert into an event queue. It is then dispatched by the event loop, and ends up in a call to some QObject's `event()` method. That's all there's to it.